# Window Functions not Working in MySQL Workbench 8.0

Tags: subquery, aggregate, grouping, window-functions, mysql-8.0

I recently updated `MySQL` to `Workbench 8.0`.  I am attempting to use the WINDOWS FUNCTIONS; however, I continually receive an `error: "Is not valid at this point expecting EOF"`.  Here is my code

```
select category_id, sum(list_price) over (partition by category_id) as total_price from products;
```

I have removed the space after over and I still receive the same error message. I greatly appreciate your help!

Below is my dataset:

[image]